# Android file picker URI to path

Tags: android

I'm trying to update an old Android application that uses absolute paths for files. Instead, the plan is to allow users to select a file. This file, an SQLite database, will then be moved to the application's data directory. The purpose is to allow users to restore backed-up versions of the app's data, overwriting what's currently there. However, after opening the file I get a URI along the lines of `/document/primary:app_name.db`, which I'm not able to open. Here's some code (target SDK version set to 28):

```
  public void importDb()
  {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    //intent.setType("application/vnd.sqlite3"); // Doesn't allow selecting the file
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
  }

  // Handle file selection here.
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
  {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
      Uri uri = data.getData();
      replaceDatabase(uri);
    }
  }

  public void replaceDatabase(Uri uri)
  {
    infile = new File(uri.getPath());

    if(!(infile.exists()))
    {
      Log.e(TAG,"Infile does not exist: " + infile); // This log error is seen, so the URI wasn't right.
      return;
    }
....
    copy(infile, outfile);
....
  }
```

Is anyone able to suggest why this is failing at the `infile.exists()` point? Presumably that Uri isn't a valid path, and if so I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to obtain one.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [File Provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider).

for example please check [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39984386/working-fileprovider-example-for-android) or [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128077/android-opening-a-file-with-action-get-content-results-into-different-uris).

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a think on this, but it does look like a more substantial change than I think I need here.